# How to populate multiple foreign keys in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

Lets say I have and object reference already set for the ids in userId:

```
{
    "__v" : 0,
    "_id" : ObjectId("530d8aa855df0c2d269a5a58"),
    "active" : false,
    "address" : "some ip address",
    "createDate" : ISODate("2014-02-26T06:33:12.367Z"),
    "displayName" : "coolguy55",
    "fullName" : "super cool guy 55",
    "userId" : [ 
        ObjectId("an ID"), 
        ObjectId("an ID")
    ]
}
```

I was wondering if it would be possible to populate both of these ids in a single populate statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your schema defines `userId` as an array of ObjectId refs to the appropriate model, calling `populate('userId')` will populate the whole array:

```
MyModel.find().populate('userId').exec(...);
```